# How to determine the type of data in a cv::Mat converted to grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm not sure where to find this information.

I loaded in a .jpg and converted it to grayscale with `cv::cvtColor(*input_image_grayscale, *input_image_grayscale, CV_BGR2GRAY);`

I then try to reference a pixel with `input_image_grayscale->at<float>(row, col)` but get an assertion error.  How do I determine the right type of data (it's clearly not float) to dereference this?  Thanks

For reference, I ran `input_image_grayscale->type()` and got 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value returned by type is just an integer that OpenCV declares with a preprocessor define. You can check it in a switch statement like this:

```
switch( matrixType )
{
    case CV_8UC1:

    .... check for other types
}
```

The `8U`, in that example refers to an unsigned char, and `C1` refers to a single channel image. CV_8UC1 is defined as `0`, so that is your Mat's type and you should use `unsigned char` for your reference type.

You can also use the function Mat::depth, to return the type of the size of a single matrix element, because you already know it is a single channel image since it is grayscale.

Comment: This is what I thought, but trying both int and unsigned return the same assertion error.  Both type and depth return 0..

Comment: @zebra If you are getting an assertion error, I am guessing it is because you are trying to access something out of the data's range. Try using `Mat::rows` and `Mat::cols` to make sure you are accessing valid pixel data with `row` and `col.`

Comment: That was my first assumption, but it's not outside of the range.  I think the type is CV_8U, but I'm trying all the data types and they aren't working correctly.  I've tried <int>, <unsigned>, <float>, <double>, all the same assertion error.  For test purposes, I am just trying to access pixel (0, 0)

Comment: Ah!  D'oh.  It's not unsigned, it's unsigned CHAR!  Thanks!